# Connecting to a Server

Tags: c#, t-sql, sqlconnection, sqlcommand, sqldataadapter

Trying to improve my C# to SQL skills... Currently I am using this bit of code to pull data from our application server. I have two different DBA's telling me two other ways to write this, just trying to figure out if this should be improved on or changed. If so, I would really appreciate some kind of examples.

FYI: This code...

```
db.con(user.Authority)
```

...Is essentially a 'new sqlconnection' code.

```
DataTable dtInfo = new DataTable("SomeInfo");
using (SqlConnection con = db.con(user.Authority))
        {
            string command = "SOME SQL STATEMENT;";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command,con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", sqlDbType).Value = Param;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                **********
                *** OR ***
                **********

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", sqlDbType).Value = Param;
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dtInfo );
                }
            }
        }
```

---

So, if I'm understanding the provided information, this is my best route?

```
        using (SqlConnection con = db.con(user.Authority))
        {
            string command = "SELECT [TBL_EMPLOYEE].[ACTIVE_DIRECTORY] FROM [TBL_EMPLOYEE];";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(reader["ACTIVE_DIRECTORY"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

And one last thing... This should prevent the need for

```
cmd.Dispose();
etc...
```

Comment: I can't tell you for sure. But, I do know that you should use Params to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the input, all queries are currently parameterized, I'll throw that in to the example just to avoid confusion though.

Comment: That's not an "or".  ExecuteNonQuery is for Inserts, Updates and Deletes, Adapter.Fill is for returning data into a dataset / datatable object.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your first example using `ExecuteNonQuery` is invalid. You would be calling `ExecuteReader`

Comment: @CharlesLambert, why is it invalid? It works flawlessly every time I use it (though I know that doesn't always mean it's right).

Comment: calling `ExecuteNonQuery` does not return any data. You need to have data returned if you expect a `DataTable` to be filled. Therefore your example should be calling `ExecuteReader` as the counter part to filling a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use the `SqlDataAdapter` version. The version that uses the `SqlCommand` object and the `SqlDataReader` will perform better, and allows more insight into the actual data being returned.

```
// Assumes the following sql:
//   SELECT foo, bar FROM baz

// error checking left out for simplicity
var list = new List<SomeClass>();
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
   while(reader.Read()) {
      list.Add(new SomeClass {
         // NOTE: you can see the columns that the c# is referencing
         //       and compare them to the sql statement being executed
         Foo = (string)reader["foo"],
         Bar = (string)reader["bar"]
      });
   }
}
```

Later as your level of experiance increases you will be able to use other features of the `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` classes in order to ensure that the code executes as quickly as possible. If you start using the `SqlDataAdapter` route, you will eventually have to relearn how to do the exact same things you have already been doing because the `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` have operations that do not exist elsewhere in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

The code would depend on the specific query.  If the query retrieves rows of data (as a SELECT does), then you would go the da.Fill() route.  If it's a query that just makes a change to the database (such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE), then you would use ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows effected.
A DataTable is not an efficient way to retrieve that number.

int rowsRet = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery)